# Minecraft: Modloader and Mods

Tags: minecraft

I was able to install the executable version of minecraft.jar for Linux, but I cannot seem to be able to install Modloader or any mods. I install the mod like I would on a PC- delete META-INF and then move the class files to minecraft.jar. Once I install Modloader and the mod which I was trying to install, which was the Timber mod, I try to execute the file and it doesn't load.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you didn't try to mod the launcher? It can be confusing that there are 2 `minecraft.jar`s, but remember that, as on Windows, you must mod the one in your `bin` folder. (Please tell me you didn't save the launcher there...)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you just did it with the minecraft launcher. This is also a jar file for linux. Are you sure you edited the file ~/.minecraft/bin/minecraft.jar and no other?

Answer (score 1):

Installing Minecraft mods in Linux is no different to doing it in Windows, and the steps you're describing appear to be correct.

Minecraft is a bit fiddly with mods and it's easy to break it if you don't follow the instructions to the letter, do not install dependencies or, say, have a wrong version of the mod.

Remove the broken minecraft.jar (or the whole bin folder) and repeat the steps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you used the launcher minecraft.jar instead of the correct one, I made the same mistake.

You need to do the steps you mentioned on the minecraft.jar file within ~/.minecraft/bin/. Then, when you are done, replace the minecraft launcher, the minecraft.jar file that you downloaded with a fresh copy.

Answer (score 0):

Since Minecraft has updated so much that the mod loader installers are basically automated
Just download it and set it to install.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is the same, sorta. With Ubuntu, you can usually right click a mod.jar file and go to properties. Navigate to the permissions tab, and make sure "Allow executing file as program" is checked. Then run it with java runtime by right clicking and selecting "Open with OpenJDK" (These are the steps I used to install optifine, but the principle is the same with other jar files that allow executing to install)